# Check if any time in a list is between two timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I am implementing some scheduled tasks in Python. The master program is running 24/7 and it runs individual tasks in a way similar to cron. I need to determine if a task should be run again from times.

In this case, I will have the time of the last run of the task, the current time (both as Unix timestamps, obtained via `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` and easily convertible to `datetime.datetime` objects), as well as the scheduled time (e.g. every 15th minute hourly, like `0:15`, `1:15`, ..., `23:15`). I want to determine if any of the scheduled times is between the last run time and the current time, probably as a boolean value. It is guaranteed that the scheduled times are always "time" (e.g. "2:00") and does not involve "date" (e.g. 1st of any month or any Monday).

Example data:

```
import datetime

scheduled = [datetime.time(h, m) for h, m in [(0, 15), (6, 15), (12, 15), (18, 15)]]
previous = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 5)
truthy = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 7)
falsey = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 6)

# some_method() is what I want
assert some_method(scheduled, previous, falsey) is False
assert some_method(scheduled, previous, truthy) is True
```

And here are some special cases that I'd also like to cover

```
scheduled = [datetime.time(1, 0)]  # 1:00 AM
previous = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 23)
truthy = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 2, 0)
falsey = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 30)

assert some_method(scheduled, previous, falsey) is False
assert some_method(scheduled, previous, truthy) is True
```

The above example should be `True` because the scheduled time "1 AM" is between "11 PM on Nov 30" and "2 AM on Dec 1". I can't compare the time directly because "1 AM" is not between "2 AM" and "11 PM" on the same day, but it's between the two times on different days.

Comment: @9769953 `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: I don't understand how/by what logic you want to compare times without days and times with days.

Comment: @timgeb It's some daily tasks that I want to determine whether they should be run again, as said in the first paragraph. Checking the time is the actual problem I'm facing.

Comment: I guess that, for each timestamp in the list, you should create two temporary datetimes with the date of the two dates you're comparing to. If either of those compares true in `(previous < temp) & (temp < next)`, then that is a valid timestamp.

Comment: So if *any* is correct (True), then the whole array is essentially correct?

Comment: @9769953 Yes. The array is the set time spots, and the return value is whether the task should be run again, which is essentially *any* of them time spots are "in between".

Comment: Does `previous = previous.time(); truthy = truthy.time(); previous < truthy and any(t < truthy for t in scheduled)` do the job?

Comment: @timgeb No. It will not work for cross-day times, as stated in the last paragraph. Also practically, the `previous` is always shortly after one of the scheduled times.

Comment: So can't you just extend your times in `scheduled` to be datetimes?

Comment: @9769953 Sorry that was a typo - the *truthy* and *falsey* are swapped in that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward method seems to be the following function:

```
def some_method(scheduled, prev, next):
    date1 = prev.date()
    date2 = next.date()
    if (next - prev).total_seconds() > 86400:
       return True
    for s in scheduled:
        for date in {date1, date2}:
            temp = datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, s.hour, s.minute, s.second)
            if prev < temp < next:
                return True
    return False
```

I'll leave it to others to prettify it, but this seems to work.

Comment: this seems like a good approach to some extents, but when `prev` is 18:00 on Nov 30 and `next` is 6:00 on Dec 2, this gives false for a scheduled time of 12:00 (which in fact, has 1 instance between, which is 12:00 on Dec 1).

Comment: @iBug See edit. Though I fear there may still be some edge cases I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `timedelta` and comparing `timetuple`s?

```
def some_method(scheduled, prev, datetime_to_check):
    yesterday = datetime_to_check - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    schedule = [(*yesterday.timetuple()[:3], s.hour, s.minute) for s in scheduled]
    schedule.extend((*datetime_to_check.timetuple()[:3], s.hour, s.minute) for s in scheduled)
    prev_tup = prev.timetuple()
    check_tup = datetime_to_check.timetuple()
    for scheduled_time in schedule:
        if prev_tup < scheduled_time < check_tup:
            return True
    return False
```